# Iterating over tf.Tensor is not allowed: AutoGraph is disabled in this function

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using tensorflow 2.1 along with python 3.7

The following snippet of code is being used to build a tensorflow graph. The code runs without errors when executed as a standalone python script. (Probably tensorflow is running in eager mode? I am not sure.)

```
import tensorflow as tf
patches = tf.random.uniform(shape=(1, 10, 50, 300), dtype=tf.dtypes.float32)
s = tf.shape(patches)
patches = [patches[0][x][y] - tf.reduce_mean(patches[0][x][y]) for y in tf.range(s[2]) for x in tf.range(s[1])]
```

However, the code fails when this is part of a tensorflow graph. I receive the following error:
tensorflow.

> python.framework.errors_impl.OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: iterating
>   over `tf.Tensor` is not allowed: AutoGraph is disabled in this function. Try decorating it directly with @tf.function.

I also added the decorator `@tf.function` to the method which wraps the above lines of code. It didn't help. I am not sure if I fully understand the meaning of decorating with `@tf.function`. I also checked that this could be a problem with using python list comprehension inside the tensorflow graph. I am not sure how to use [tf.map_fn](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/map_fn) or [tf.while_loop](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/while_loop) for my case, since I have nested loops.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

List comprehensions are not yet supported in autograph. The error that's raised needs to be improved, too. Piling up on https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/32546 should help resolve it sooner.

Until comprehensions are supported, you have to use map_fn, which in this case would look something like this:

```
def outer_comp(x):
  def inner_comp(y):
    return patches[0][x][y] - tf.reduce_mean(patches[0][x][y])
  return tf.map_fn(inner_comp, tf.range(s[2]), dtype=tf.float32)
patches = tf.map_fn(outer_comp, tf.range(s[1]), dtype=tf.float32)
```

That said, I believe you can just use reduce_mean directly:

```
patches = patches - tf.expand_dims(tf.reduce_mean(patches, axis=3), -1)
```

Comment: This is excellent! The nested definitions where each of them returns a  `map_fn` indeed is the solution for any nested implementations. Thanks for also adding the method to directly compute the mean.

Answer (score -6):

This naturally works in tf version: 2.5.0. Now you can use the nested comprehensions directly.

Comment: I have tested with TF 2.7 and it does not work.