# Why Iterating over tf.Tensor is not allowed in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm using @tf.function to decorate functions for speed boost, but run into an error when I try to iterate over tf.range().
This error can be recreated using following code

```
@tf.function
def loop(x, y):
    for i in tf.range(1,100,dtype=tf.int64):
        x.assign_add(y)
    return x
```

My tensorflow version is 1.15. I don't want to replace tf.range() with range, as in my knowledge it will unroll the for-loop body. Is there any methods to solve this problem?

ERROR information is below

```
OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: iterating over `tf.Tensor` is not allowed: AutoGraph did not convert this function. Try decorating it directly with @tf.function
```

Comment: please provide error... why not using tf 2 ?

Comment: I uploaded the error information. And, it's very cumbersome to adapt my project to tf2...

Comment: look at that - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62068323/iterating-over-tf-tensor-is-not-allowed-autograph-is-disabled-in-this-function

Comment: I would agree that switching to TF2 would be the most "sane" solution for many reasons. If this is not possible, the only way I am aware of to loop in TF 1.x is by using [scan](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/scan) or [fold](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/foldl). Unfortunately I lack the time to prepare a proper answer on how to use these functions. They can be cumbersome to use. The previous comment also proposes `map_fn` for a similar use case.