# Decode JPEG from tfrecords error: ValueError: Shape must be rank 0 but is rank 1 for 'DecodeJpeg' (op: 'DecodeJpeg') with input shapes: [?]

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I applied the method in this [github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/9675) to write JPEG files into .tfrecords. But I have issues when parsing them.

Here's my code for writing the tfrecords, each `x_img` is a numpy array, and each `x_img[i]` contains fixed amount of `img_bytes`

```
img_bytes = open(join(frames_path, vid, img_list[current]),'rb').read()
...
"x_img": tf.train.Feature( bytes_list = tf.train.BytesList( value= x_img[i])),
```

When parsing, I did this:

```
def parse_func(example_proto):

    # FEATURES
    feature_description = {
        "x_img": tf.io.VarLenFeature(tf.string),
        }
    feat = tf.io.parse_single_example(example_proto, feature_description)
        
    x = {}
    x_img = tf.sparse.to_dense(feat["x_img"])
    x_img = tf.io.decode_jpeg(x_img, channels = 3)

    x["x_img"] = x_img/255

    
    return x
```

But it returns error:

```
ValueError: Shape must be rank 0 but is rank 1 for 'DecodeJpeg' (op: 'DecodeJpeg') with input shapes: [?].
```

What is the right way to decode a JPEG which was previously stored in bytes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Full answer:

`tf.io.decode_jpeg` works fine. The reason I got the error is that I shaped the input as `(n, width, height, 3)`. But the function `decode_jpeg` only works on a single image instead of n images.

By writing:

```
x_img = tf.stack([
    tf.io.decode_jpeg(x_images[0], channels = 3),
    tf.io.decode_jpeg(x_images[1], channels = 3),
    tf.io.decode_jpeg(x_images[2], channels = 3),
])
```

I could recover the bytes to JPEG. The more efficient way is using list comprehension, but unfortunately, list comprehension is not supported now (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62068323/iterating-over-tf-tensor-is-not-allowed-autograph-is-disabled-in-this-function)).

The reason for writing bytes into `.tfrecords` instead of using `plt.imread()` or `cv2.imread()` is that it doesn't decompress the image, so the process would be much faster and space-efficient. I didn't calculate it precisely, but decompressing JPEG images leads ~6x increase in disk space.