# Equivalent of np.isin for TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

I have `categories` as a list of list integers as shown below:

```py
categories = [
 [0,2,4,6,8],
 [1,3,5,7,9]  
]
```

I have a label tensor `y` with `num_batches` integers (as classes):

```py
y = tf.constant([0, 1, 1, 2, 5, 4, 7, 9, 3, 3])
```

I want to replace values in `y` with certain indices (let's say 0-even, 1-odd) with the `categories` list available, such that final result would be:

```py
cat_labels = tf.constant([0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

I can get it by iterating through each value in `y` like below:

```py
cat_labels = tf.Variable(tf.identity(y))
for idx in range(len(categories)):
    for i, _y in enumerate(y):
        if _y in categories[idx]: # if _y value is in categories[idx]
            cat_labels[i].assign(idx) # replace all of them with idx
```

But apparently iterating is not allowed when this block is encapsulated in a `@tf.function` parent function.

Is there a way to apply the logic without iterating, or converting to numpy and applying `np.isin`, while getting speedups of `tf.function`?

Edit: There seem to be workarounds on this like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62068323/iterating-over-tf-tensor-is-not-allowed-autograph-is-disabled-in-this-function), but any help on explaining in the context of this use case would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `tf.map_fn` in the following way:

```py
y = tf.constant([0., 1., 1., 2., 5., 4., 7., 9., 3., 3.], dtype=tf.float32)
categories = [[0,2,4,6,8],[1,3,5,7,9]]
c = tf.convert_to_tensor(categories, dtype=tf.float32)


cat_labels = tf.map_fn(                          # apply an operation on all of the elements of Y
     lambda x:tf.gather_nd(                      # get index of category: 0 or 1 or anything else
                        tf.cast(                 # cast dtype of the result of the inner function
                            tf.where(            # get index of the element of Y in categories
                                tf.equal(c, x)), # search an element of Y within categories
                                    dtype=tf.float32),[0,0]), y)

tf.print(cat_labels, summarize=-1)
# [0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1]
```