# How to read files in parallel with tf.data.Dataset.from_generator?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-hub

I have successfully created a TF dataset using `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator` that reads several binary files in sequence and converts them to strings. The code looks like this:

```
my_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
                lambda: _generate_data_points(fnames), tf.string)
```

The generator does something like this:

```
for fname in fnames:
    for data_point in read_binary_file(fname):
        yield data_point
```

However, I would like to read the files in parallel using `dataset.interleave`. Since this operates on an existing dataset, I first created one like this:

```
my_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(fnames)
```

I then changed my generator to operate on a single file and integrated it into dataset.interleave as follows:

```
my_dataset = my_dataset.interleave(
    lambda fname: _generate_data_points(fname),
    cycle_length=8)
```

It seems as if TF is now expecting my generator to operate on Tensors instead of regular types though, because I get the following error message:

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

As far as I know, this usually means that we need to wrap with `tf.py_function`, but when I do that I get:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: Iterating over a symbolic `tf.Tensor` is not allowed: AutoGraph is disabled in this function. Try decorating it directly with @tf.function.
```

Here’s how I did the wrapping:

```
for data_point in tf.py_function(
        func=read_binary_file,
        inp=[file],
        Tout=tf.string):
    yield data_point
```

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62068323/iterating-over-tf-tensor-is-not-allowed-autograph-is-disabled-in-this-function) that gets the same error message, and they suggest using `tf.map_fn`. However, I am not applying my function to multiple arguments. Instead, I am returning multiple values by applying it to a single argument.

Not sure where to go from here...